# Newtonsoft JSON get specific nested property at runtime

Tags: c#, json

How can I get the value of a specific nested property, from a JSON object, at runtime?
Here is an example that ilustrates what I am trying to do (without error checking, because it's just a quick example):

JSON Object:

```
string jsonobj = "{ 
    "Header":"someHeader",
    "FirstNest":{
        "Property1":"123",
        "property2":"321",
        "SecondNest":{
            "property3":"456",
            "property4":"789"
        }
    }
```

In my code, I would have something like this :

`string read = Console.ReadLine();`

where the user will input, for example `FirstNest.Property1` and then I would return `123`. I could do something like this:

```
JObject msg = JObject.Parse(jsonobj);
string[] tosearch = read.Split('.'); // This would give me FirstNest Property1
string tofind = (string)msg[tosearch[0]][tosearch[1]];
```

The problem arises when the user wants to access `FirstNest.SecondNest.property3`, because my hard-coded method can only take two strings. How can I build such a "query" method at runtime, with which I could enable the user to search for any property?
One soultion would be to make a function

```
GetProperty(JObject msg, string str1, string str2)
{
    return (string)msg[str1][str2];
}
```

then another one , which would take 3 strings as input :

```
GetProperty(JObject msg, string str1, string str2, string str3)
{
    return (string)msg[str1][str2][str3];
}
```

, then another one, which would take 4 strings as input, and so on... which doesn't seem like an efficient solution.

Comment: I think [`SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) already does what you want, doesn't it?

Comment: @dbc You are right, that is the best sollution to the problem (allthough Jason Boyd's solution also works). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this (exception handling excluded for brevity):

```
public string GetJsonPropertyValue(string json, string query)
{
    JToken token = JObject.Parse(json);

    foreach(string queryComponent in query.Split('.'))
    {
        token = token[queryComponent];
    }
    return token.ToString();
}
```

Given the json in your example a search for this `FirstNest.SecondNest.property3` will return `456`. You should include any necessary user input validation and exception handling.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Do you perhaps have an idea how I could also access arrays with indexes?

Comment: Ok, I found a solution for numbers too: `int n;
                bool isNumber = int.TryParse(queryComponent, out n);
                if (isNumber)
                {
                    token = token[n];
                }
                else
                {
                    token = token[queryComponent];
                }`